# Transform Heavy right tailed data

Tags: clustering, k-means, heavy-tailed, logarithm

I am clustering (K-MEANS) a data 1.7million observations, which displays a heavy-tailed distribution when examined by plot. What is the best transformation to correct it. does log can handle this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! The log transformation is perfect for this sort of right-tailed data. 
Alternatively, a different member of the [Box-Cox family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation) might help, depending on what you're using the data for.

Comment: Ok thanks, coul help me to for the syntax if I want to transform many variables at the same time? I'm sas starter.

Comment: No clue sorry. I use R.